# How to display two items in column per item in carousel PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have a carousel which has to display two items per column in each item. I tried using foreach method and array_chunk() to do so, but it doesn't seem to do the work.
This is the code I am working with:

```
<div class="section cataloge">
<div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cataloge-page">
            <?php
            if ($cataloge->have_posts()) {
            ?>
                <div class="cataloge-slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <?php
                    while ($cataloge->have_posts()) {
                        $cataloge->the_post();
                        $input_array = array($cataloge);
                        foreach (array_chunk($input_array, 2, true) as $column) {
                    ?>
                            <div class="cataloge-slider-item-wrapper">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($column as $input_array) {
                                   
                                ?>
                                    <article class="cataloge-item">
                                        <figure class="cataloge-item-img img-placeholder">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                            <?php
                                            if (!empty(get_field('sticky_text'))) {
                                            ?>
                                                <div class="cataloge-sticky"><?php the_field('sticky_text'); ?></div>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </figure>
                                        <div class="cataloge-item-data">
                                            <h4 class="cataloge-item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                            <div class="cataloge-item-category">
                                                <?php
                                                if (have_rows('cataloge_category')) {
                                                    while (have_rows('cataloge_category')) {
                                                        the_row();
                                                ?>
                                                        <?php
                                                        if (!empty(get_sub_field('cataloge_category_item'))) {
                                                        ?>
                                                            <span><?php the_sub_field('cataloge_category_item'); ?></span>
                                                        <?php
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="cataloge-item-info"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                                            <div class="cataloge-item-action">
                                                <?php
                                                if (!empty(get_field('cataloge_file'))) {
                                                ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_field('cataloge_file'); ?>">
                                                        <svg width='25' height='25'>
                                                            <use xlink:href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/frontend/fontawesome/solid.svg#eye'></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                                <?php
                                                if (!empty(get_field('cataloge_download_file'))) {
                                                ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_field('cataloge_download_file'); ?>" download="">
                                                        <svg width='25' height='25'>
                                                            <use xlink:href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/frontend/fontawesome/solid.svg#download'></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is it that I'm missing? Is there another way, other than foreach or/and array_chunk to get the result?

Comment: Your code is quite difficult to read, which is due to the mixing of PHP and HTML code. I agree that, to some extent, this is unavoidable. But you can separate processing the data from the actual output of HTML. For instance, use pure PHP to create a single array, which you then output with almost pure HTML. This would also make it easier to see if you're now dealing with a PHP or a HTML problem.

Comment: `$input_array = array($cataloge);` - you now created an array that contains`$cataloge` as its _single_ item. Trying to chunk an array that contains only one single element, into "arrays of two items each", does not make too much sense. Assuming `$cataloge` is a `WP_Query` instance, this should be `$input_array = $cataloge->posts;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few problems that you're going to run into doing it this way. To address the main problem, you're using array_chunk on the entire query object, not just the posts. This might be why it's not working as expected. You would probably want to do `array_chunk($cataloge->posts)` to chunk them.

However you've put this loop in a loop of all your posts, which means each iteration of that loop will repeat this. So if you have 10 posts in your $cataloge query, you'll end up with 50 slides, with 45 of them being duplicates. If we instead use a foreach loop with the array_chunk outside of the while loop (remembering to use [setup_postdata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/)) we should be more on the right track:

```
<div class="section cataloge">
  <div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cataloge-page">
        <?php if ($cataloge->have_posts()) { ?>
          <div class="cataloge-slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <?php $input_array = array($cataloge->posts);
            foreach (array_chunk($input_array, 2, true) as $column) { ?>
              <div class="cataloge-slider-item-wrapper">
                <?php foreach ($column as $input_array) {
                  setup_postdata($column); ?>
                  <article class="cataloge-item">
                    <figure class="cataloge-item-img img-placeholder">
                      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                      <?php if (!empty(get_field('sticky_text'))) { ?>
                        <div class="cataloge-sticky"><?php the_field('sticky_text'); ?></div>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="cataloge-item-data">
                      <h4 class="cataloge-item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                      <div class="cataloge-item-category">
                        <?php if (have_rows('cataloge_category')) {
                          while (have_rows('cataloge_category')) {
                            the_row();
                            if (!empty(get_sub_field('cataloge_category_item'))) { ?>
                              <span><?php the_sub_field('cataloge_category_item'); ?></span>
                            <?php }
                          }
                        } ?> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="cataloge-item-info"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                      <div class="cataloge-item-action">
                        <?php if (!empty(get_field('cataloge_file'))) { ?>
                          <a href="<?php the_field('cataloge_file'); ?>">
                            <svg width='25' height='25'>
                              <use xlink:href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/frontend/fontawesome/solid.svg#eye'></use>
                            </svg>
                          </a> 
                        <?php }
                        if (!empty(get_field('cataloge_download_file'))) { ?>
                          <a href="<?php the_field('cataloge_download_file'); ?>" download="">
                            <svg width='25' height='25'>
                              <use xlink:href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/frontend/fontawesome/solid.svg#download'></use>
                            </svg>
                          </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                <?php }
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
              </div>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is it! It was of great help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug by `echo` or `print_r` step by step.

I think problem here `$input_array = array($cataloge);`
Change to `$input_array = (array) $cataloge;`